# Jenkins Workflow Shell Step and Passwords

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

Is there a way with the Jenkins Workflow 'sh' step to hide or mask whats being executed from the builds console output?

I'm currently using it to execute a command that contains a password and this is being exposed in plain text in the build output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the [Credentials Binding plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) and use the `withCredentials` step to obtain your password from a secure source. It will be automatically suppressed from any build output within that block.

Comment: I've tried doing this unfortunately even using code generated by the snippet generator I get the error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: USERNAME for class: WorkflowScript`

Comment: Ok this seems to be because the documentation might be wrong you have to use env.USERNAME.

Comment: `env.PROP` from within Groovy code. To external processes it is just an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin)
This will allow you to mask the password variable in the job & its output.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the way I'm using workflow, I think the fact its a password gets lost once you go into the workflow script so the plugin doesn't mask it.